# ruby Fakeweb error if a Mechanize agent's read_timeout= is called

Tags: ruby, mechanize, fakeweb

I'm using Mechanize to spider some websites. While spidering I save pages to files that I use later with Fakeweb to do tests.

My Mechanize agent is created this way:

```
Mechanize.new do |a| 
  a.read_timeout = 20 # doesn't work with Fakeweb?
  a.max_history = 1 
end
```

When I run my app enabling Fakeweb to fetch files instead of actual Internet access, my log throws these messages for every uri I try

```
W, [2011-08-20T18:49:45.764749 #14526]  WARN -- : undefined method `read_timeout=' for #<FakeWeb::StubSocket:0xb72c150c>
```

If I comment the second line in the above code (`# a.read_timeout = 20 ...`), it works perfectly. No problem at all. Any idea on how to enable read_timout and make Fakeweb work?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monkey patching is often a kludge but I think it is reasonable here:

```
module FakeWeb
  class StubSocket
    def read_timeout=(ignored)
    end
  end
end
```

Timeouts don't have much meaning in the fake world so ignoring them seems like a reasonable thing to do.

You might even consider sending a [pull request](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/blob/master/lib/fake_web/stub_socket.rb) to the author.